# Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'XmlNode'

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio, dart, clone

Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'XmlNode'.

- 'XmlNode' is from 'package:xml/src/xml/nodes/node.dart' ('/C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/xml-6.2.2/lib/src/xml/nodes/node.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  .map((node) => node.value)

Anyone had experience with this error

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same issue i changed

> from this

```
final text = element.children
    .where((node) => node is XmlText || node is XmlCDATA)
    .map((node) => node.value)
    .join()
    .trim();
```

> to this

```
final text = element.children
    .where((node) => node is XmlText || node is XmlCDATA)
    .map((node) => node.text) //change value to text 
    .join()
    .trim();
```

in `/home/munsif/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/pdf-3.10.2/lib/src/svg/text.dart`
and this solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to solve it by editing the local cache.

The error happens because you need to update xml version to >= 6.3.0

if you are not using xml directly in pubspec.yaml, then there are packages that you are using depend on the xml package and you have to update them.

To know which packages depend on xml, run `flutter pub deps`

Answer (score 0):

I cleared that error.I added 2 dependancys pdf and xml for testing. but i didnt  used that.

then i deleted from pubspec.yamel.But the dependecys cache stored in pubspec.lock.

then i dlt 2 dependancys caches but that regenerate itselt.them i edited that dependancys pub.dev link and runned success fully

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).